# Delphi: Ошибка доступа в AppData

Tags: delphi

Вот такая ошибка происходит, при взаимодействии с папкой AppData/Roaming.
Как это исправить?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может у тя прав нету на открытие папки?